# Way to set text style programmatically in Android widget?

Tags: android, text, coding-style, widget

I see there is a `TextAppearanceSpan` available but no examples on usage. I just want to make the text bold and leave everything else unchanged - is there perhaps a simpler way to do this programmatically?

Comment: FYI, this is for setting the title on a Tab widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to create an xml file in res/values and write something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="header">
        /** here goes the style */
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then all your need is to pass generated R.style.header to the TextAppearanceSpan constructor.

Comment: My tabs are TextViews, so I ended up using the Spannable class to apply styling.

Answer (score 2):

It is documented at
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext
, look at the second way using `Spannable`.

Specifically

```
// Get our EditText object.
EditText vw = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text); // or new etc

// Set the EditText's text.
vw.setText("Italic, highlighted, bold.");

// Get the EditText's internal text storage
Spannable str = vw.getText();

// Create our span sections, and assign a format to each.
str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC), 0, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 8, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 21, str.length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```